# Bug in JLine2? ConsoleReader.clearScreen

Tags: java, jline

---

EDIT: This [feature](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/undocumented-feature.html) only occurs when I invoke the `clearScreen` method of `ConsoleReader`! Any other changes don't have an effect. Is this then a bug in JLine2?

---

JLine2:

Why, when I run this, do I get two console prompts directly following each other (`----> ---->`)?
Is it because two consoles are being created? I do not understand how.
What am I failing to see here?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import jline.console.ConsoleReader;

class TextUi implements Ui {
    private static final String prompt1 = "---->  ";
    public void homeScreen() {
        try {
            ConsoleReader con = new ConsoleReader();
            con.setPrompt(prompt1);

            con.clearScreen();
            System.out.println("Press any key to continue...");
            con.readCharacter();
            con.clearScreen();

            System.out.println("Here is a prompt. Do something and press enter to continue...");
            String line = con.readLine();
            con.clearScreen();

            System.out.println("You typed: ");
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("Press any key to exit. ");
            con.readCharacter();
            con.clearScreen();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }   
    }   
    public void exitSplash() {
        System.out.println("Thank You. Goodbye.");
        System.out.println("");
    }   
    public void creditsScreen() {
    }   
    public static void main (String argv[]) {
            TextUi ui = new TextUi();
            ui.homeScreen();
            ui.exitSplash();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What version of jline are you using?

Comment: JLine2. Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, you just need to call `con.flush()` after each time you call `con.clearScreen()`.

The `clearScreen` method doesn't calls `flush()` automatically (it might work in some cases without flushing) but the `readLine` method does, so the screen is actually clearing only when you call `con.readLine()`. This is causing to the last `System.out.println` (before the `readLine`) to be cleared even it was called after `con.clearScreen()`.

Your code inside the `try` block should be changed to:

```
ConsoleReader con = new ConsoleReader();
con.setPrompt(prompt1);

con.clearScreen();
con.flush();
System.out.println("Press any key to continue...");
con.readCharacter();
con.clearScreen();
con.flush();

System.out.println("Here is a prompt. Do something and press enter to continue...");
String line = con.readLine();
con.clearScreen();
con.flush();

System.out.println("You typed: ");
System.out.println(line);
System.out.println("Press any key to exit. ");
con.readCharacter();
con.clearScreen();
con.flush();
```